# How to use GROUP_CONCAT with MAX(CASE WHEN...)?

Tags: mysql, case, group-concat

I want to take result from this query but i have problem in using group_concat with max case.

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.f_name THEN t2.name END) AS name2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.l_name THEN t2.name END) AS name3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.a_name THEN t2.name END) AS name4,
  GROUP_CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.vehicles) THEN t3.name END) AS car_owned)
  GROUP_CONCAT(MAX(CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.homes) THEN t3.name END) AS home_owned)
FROM
  first_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN second_table AS t2
  ON t2.code IN (t1.f_name, t1.l_name, t1.a_name)
  LEFT JOIN second_table AS t3 ON FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.vehicles) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.homes) > 0
GROUP BY
  t1.id,
  t1.name
```

for any help thanks. fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0e08/1)

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do

Comment: @Strawberry I have problem in selecting concatenated column in first_table column home and vehicles has concatenated value that came from second table now i want to take related name from second_table.

Comment: @Mureinik Now i fiddle is available.

Comment: On its own. the fiddle won't help (me) much because we(/I) still can't see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Strawberry I want to take related value from second table to the concatenated value of column vehicles in first_table

Comment: A couple of issues. You are trying to use an aggregate function (GROUP_CONCAT) on the result of an aggregate function (MAX). I am not quite sure why you are trying to do that (it looks like you are trying to find a matching vehicle and get the highest one, then group that single highest one together). It looks like either MAX or GROUP_CONCAT is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.f_name THEN t2.name END AS name2,
  CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.l_name THEN t2.name END AS name3,
  CASE WHEN t2.code = t1.a_name THEN t2.name END AS name4,
  CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.vehicles) > 0 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t3.name END)) AS car_owned)
  CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.homes) > 0 THEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t3.name)) END AS home_owned)
FROM
  first_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN second_table AS t2
  ON t2.code IN (t1.f_name, t1.l_name, t1.a_name)
  LEFT JOIN second_table AS t3 ON FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.vehicles) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(t3.code,t1.homes) > 0
GROUP BY
  t1.id,
  t1.name
```

fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0e08/6)